# how to add 2 charts in same excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am able to add one chart to a excel sheet but in case of 2 charts my method is not working. I am using following code to add 2 charts

```
//chart 1
Excel.ChartObjects chartObjs = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects();
Excel.ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(150, 150, 600, 600);
Excel.Chart xlChart = chartObj.Chart;
Excel.Range xValues = xlWorkSheet.Range["A6", "A262"];
Excel.Range values = xlWorkSheet.Range["B6", "B262"];

var range = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A6", "A262");
xlChart.SetSourceData(range);

Excel.Range chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A6:A262");
xlChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, Type.Missing);
xlChart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
xlChart.HasLegend = false;

Excel.Series series = (Excel.Series)(xlChart.SeriesCollection(1));
series.XValues = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B2:B262");

//2nd chart
Excel.ChartObject chartObj1 = chartObjs.Add(300, 300, 400, 400);
Excel.Chart xlChart1 = chartObj1.Chart;

xlChart1.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
Excel.Series series1 = (Excel.Series)(xlChart1.SeriesCollection(1));  -- line1
series1.Values = currentVY;
series1.XValues = currentVX;
```

Where I am making mistake in my code? I am getting error at line1 "invalid parameter".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the range and pass it to SetSourceData method for the second chart before you even take the SeriesCollection object.

Something like

```
var range2 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D6", "D262");
xlChart1.SetSourceData(range2);
```

But I would recommend that you use 3rd party libraries based on Microsoft's OpenXML SDK because if you are going to have your application on Server it will give you headache when there is a Microsoft Office update and Application with Excel Automation is not a good trend as it haunts you forever when the application goes live.

Use SpreadSheetLight ([Download here](http://spreadsheetlight.com/download/)) by Vincent Tan along with DocumentFormat.OpenXml (2.0) library ([Download here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeplex.com%2FProject%2FDownload%2FFileDownload.aspx%3FProjectName%3Dclosedxml%26DownloadId%3D177539&ei=REa-VJb_ONXf8AXAyIGYBg&usg=AFQjCNGlifv38kpy0U4CmUPCOP650r3YTg&bvm=bv.83829542,d.dGc))

or

**Spire.XLS by E-Iceblue** which adds a watermark sheet though.